# Navbar won't toggle when window resizes

Tags: jquery, html, css, toggle, navbar

I have created a side navbar toggle menu that sticks to the page. The problem is when I resize my window screen it won't toggle except when the page is scrolled to the top.

HTML

```
  <i class="fa fa-bars fa-2x nav-toggle"></i>
  <nav class="main-navigation">
   <ul class='nav-links'>
    <li><a href="#home">Home</a></li>
    <li><a href="#about">About</a></li>
    <li><a href="#skills">Skills</a></li>
    <li><a href="#portfolio">Portfolio</a></li>
    <li><a href="#contact">Contact</a></li>
    </ul>
     </nav>
```

CSS

```
.main-navigation {
position: fixed;
top:0;
left:0;
width: 100px;
height: 100px;
text-align: center;
transform: translateY(-210%);
transition: transform 0.6s ease;
}

.main-navigation.open {
transform: translateY(50%);
}
```

JS

```
$('.nav-toggle').on('click', function(){
    $('.main-navigation').toggleClass('open');
});
```

Comment: Please, provide jsfiddle.

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/7grquucm/

Comment: Your `.main-navigation` must have `position:fixed`?

Comment: Yes because I want it to be accessible through the webpage. Plus my toggle isn't opening after the code you gave me.

Comment: The problem is `position:fixed`. You can use `position:relative;` when the windows size is small.

Comment: Check [this](https://jsfiddle.net/alireza_safian/7grquucm/1/)

Comment: It's still not working. My goal is to allow the user to click the icon button to navigate through the webpage where ever he is. Even when I change the position to relative I'm still having the same issue.

Answer (score 0):

HTML:

```
<i class="fa fa-bars fa-2x nav-toggle"></i>
  <nav class="open">
   <ul class='nav-links'>
    <li><a href="#home">Home</a></li>
    <li><a href="#about">About</a></li>
    <li><a href="#skills">Skills</a></li>
    <li><a href="#portfolio">Portfolio</a></li>
    <li><a href="#contact">Contact</a></li>
   </ul>
  </nav>
```

CSS:

```
.open {
position: fixed;
top:0;
left:0;
width: 100px;
height: 100px;
text-align: center;
transform: translateY(-210%);
transition: transform 0.6s ease;
}

.open.toggle {
transform: translateY(50%);
}
```

JQUERY:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var width = $(window).width();
if(width < 768){
   $(".nav-toggle").click(function(){
     $(".open").toggle();
     $(".open").toggleClass("toggle");
  });
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

This is the code your are looking for:

```
$(window).resize(function (){
if(window.width() < YOUR PREFERENCE) {

Insert your toggle code here

}
});
```

Comment: The toggle menu not opening